How can I map a field of a polars struct from values of another field `a`, to values of another field `b`?
I have a Polars dataframe with these columns. I want to replace the values in each list in column C with the corresponding value in column b, based on the position the value in c has in column a.
┌────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ a                  ┆ b                               ┆ c                  │
│ ---                ┆ ---                             ┆ ---                │
│ list[f32]          ┆ list[f64]                       ┆ list[f32]          │
╞════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [1.0, 0.0]         ┆ [0.001143, 0.998857]            ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 1.5]  │
│ [5.0, 6.0, … 4.0]  ┆ [0.000286, 0.000143, … 0.00357… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 6.5]  │
│ [1.0, 0.0]         ┆ [0.005287, 0.994713]            ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 1.5]  │
│ [0.0, 1.5, … 2.5]  ┆ [0.84367, 0.003858, … 0.000429… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 3.5]  │
│ [5.0, 6.0, … 1.0]  ┆ [0.001286, 0.000286, … 0.35267… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 6.5]  │
│ …                  ┆ …                               ┆ …                  │
│ [0.0, 1.0]         ┆ [0.990283, 0.009717]            ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 1.5]  │
│ [5.0, 1.0, … 0.0]  ┆ [0.003001, 0.352672, … 0.42855… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 6.5]  │
│ [0.0, 2.0, … 3.0]  ┆ [0.90383, 0.004716, … 0.000143… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 3.5]  │
│ [2.0, 0.0, … 9.0]  ┆ [0.233352, 0.060446, … 0.00228… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 10.5] │
│ [5.0, 8.0, … 11.0] ┆ [0.134467, 0.022578, … 0.00085… ┆ [0.0, 0.5, … 12.5] │
└────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘

Here is my attempt:
df = df.with_columns(
        pl.struct("a", "b", "c").alias("d").struct.with_fields(
            pl.field("c").replace(old=pl.field("a"), new=pl.field("b"), default=0)
    )
)

Unfortunately, this yields the error *** polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: `old` input for `replace` must not contain duplicates. However, "a", the field being passed to the old argument is column "a", which is the unique values from Expr.value_counts(), so it shouldn't contain any duplicates. And indeed,  df.select(pl.col("lines").list.eval(pl.element().is_duplicated().any()).explode().any()) returns false.
Small chunk of the data to reproduce:
df = pl.DataFrame([
    pl.Series('a', [[1.0, 0.0], [5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 2.5], [5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0]]),
    pl.Series('b', [[0.0011431837667905116, 0.9988568162332095], [0.0002857959416976279, 0.00014289797084881395, 0.2842240640182909, 0.5985995998856817, 0.019291226064589884, 0.09388396684767077, 0.003572449271220349], [0.005287224921406116, 0.9947127750785939], [0.8436696198913975, 0.0038582452129179764, 0.00014289797084881395, 0.10703058016576164, 0.007859388396684767, 0.03701057444984281, 0.00042869391254644185], [0.0012860817376393256, 0.0002857959416976279, 0.4645613032294941, 0.038153758216633325, 0.13561017433552444, 0.007430694484138326, 0.3526721920548728]]),
    pl.Series('c', [[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5], [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5], [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5], [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5], [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]]),
])

Example of what the output should be:
For the first row, the new column/struct field should look like [0.998857, 0, ..., 0], because the values of "c" are [0.0, 0.5, ... 1.5] and 0 is at index 1 in column "a", and the value at index 1 in column "b" is 0.998857. The other values of 0.5 and 1.5 would be the default 0 as they do not appear in "a".
Is this just not possible? I am really hoping to find a vectorized way to do this.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

So you want the first item in column c to be [0.998875, 0.001143, ..., 1.5]?

@James For the first row, the new column/struct field should look like [0.998857, 0, ..., 0], because 0 is at index 1 in column "a", and the value at index 1 in column "b" is 0.998857. The other values would be the default 0 as their values do not appear in "a".

It would be much easier to help if you gave sample code to run e.g.  the output of df.head().to_init_repr() - along with the full expected output. It's difficult to tell due to the missing data in the current repr example.

@jqurious Thank you, I was not aware of to_init_repr().

You want to treat column c which has '0.5, 1.5, etc' as an index column? How do you want to handle those non-whole number cases?

@DeanMacGregor More like I want to map the values of each list in column c call them i, to the value in column b's list at index X, where X is in the index at which value i is located in column a. It should just be what polars.Expr.replace does, mapping values from one sequence to another. I edited the post to include more info.

@GBPU row 0 or column c contains ALL of the values of column a: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5].  The output for that row should be [0.998857, 0.001143, 0, 0], correct?

@James Column c is this pl.col("uniques").alias("test").list.eval(pl.element().struct[0].append(pl.element().struct[0] + 0.5).sort(). It is a sorted sequence of numbers from the min to the max+0.5 of each row's list in column a, in intevals of 0.5. That is why row 0 "c" is [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5], and I want it transformed into [0.998857, 0, 0.001143, 0]

Let's take an inventory of all the things we need for this to work which won't necessarily be the order we accomplish them, moreso in the order you might think of each thing.

Compare list columns by element, this can't be done directly, need explode
Since the columns to compare aren't equal size/shape, they should be separated in their own dfs before explode and then joined
Create a row index of the original df so when the separated dfs are joined, the original row index will be one of the keys
Create an element index of the a column since we'll need to use those values explicitly.
group by the original df's row index to make a new list of index positions
join the new df of list element index positions to the original df and gather by that new index column.
replace the nulls with 0 of the final column

Here's the code
df = df.with_row_index("i") # item 3

# item 2
a = df.select("i", "a", 
              ai=pl.int_ranges(0, pl.col("a").list.len()) # item 4
              ).explode("a", "ai") # item 1
c = df.select("i","c").explode("c") # item 1

ai = (
    # item 2
    a.join(c, left_on=["a", "i"], right_on=["c", "i"], how="right")
    # item 5
    .group_by("i", maintain_order=True)
    .agg("ai")
)

df = (
    df
    .join(ai, on="i") #item 6
    .with_columns(
        z=pl.col("b").list.gather("ai")
        .list.eval(pl.element().fill_null(0)) #item 7
    )
    .drop('i')
)

